# Need help recovering files from a Laptop with broken screen

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

#### I have a laptop with important data stored on it.

Unfortunately, **the LCD of that laptop is broken,** thus unuseable.

I would like to recover files from a specific directory, but that laptop lacks an HDMI port, I have a USB, and an Android device. My laptop runs Windows 7.

#### What can I do to get my data back?

Comment: Thats easy - recover them from your backup.  You do have a backup of-course, because the files are important.  (If you don't back them up they are obviously not important)

Comment: @davidgo That was a lot of help!

Comment: That was the answer I was going to give. If they are important then there are (multiple) backups.

Answer (score 5):

Open up the Laptop, take out the harddisk/SSD, connect it to some other computer using an internal SATA connection, an external SATA-to-USB adapter, a docking station or any other way you like.

Now, you can read and retreive all that importand data.

Answer (score 2):

### Your data is undamaged and intact.

The data is intact, provided, that the rest of the laptop, specifically the hard drive was not damaged.

One possibility without opening the laptop would be making use of other display output ports than HDMi.

The other possibility is opening the laptop and retrieving the data storage device from inside, and connecting it to a different and working computer.
Use a SATA-to-USB adapter. The SSD/HDD will be treated like an ordinary external storage device.

Comment: (Misspellings in your profile's "About me" section: *"sonce January 2018"* and *"StackExchange"*. *"[since](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/since#Adverb) January 2018"* and *"[Stack Exchange](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance)"* (the last section), respectively.)